# Eclipse behavior in Netbeans

Tags: java, php, eclipse, configuration, netbeans6.7

I love Netbeans but there is one thing I really like about Eclipse that I can't do in Netbeans:

If I have started a function that takes a string i.e. someFunction("Some string here")

Both netbeans and eclipse will autocomplete the ending doublequote and parens.

In Eclipse, if I hit enter at the end of my string, the cursor will move outside these.

In Netbeans, it will do a newline.

Anyone know how to make Netbeans behave like Eclipse in this manner?

Answer (score 0):

It's an entirely differently application that uses very different APIs for their editors. Short of writing a custom plugin, I don't think you can.

Answer (score 0):

This is a usablity issue. I think NetBeans has not support this yet.